# Using Captive Network Assistant on MacOSX to connect to VPN

Tags: osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, vpn, autologin

Apple introduced a new "feature" with MacOSX Lion (10.7) which is called Captive Network Assistant. In my opinion its just a useless and annoying feature. It's aim is to help you login to networks which require authentication (see: [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)), but the feature doesn't store cookies or saves passwords.

In my university we also use such a network which requires users to login. The login doesn't happen via browser but via VPN, which makes the Captive Network Assistant completely useless and annoying.

So im posting a Guide here on how to replace this "feature" with something actually useful and i didn't want it to get lost and be useful to other people

**#1.** create a bash script with name "Captive Network Assistant", paste the following code inside and replace your file with the same at */System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/*

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptlocation="/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/vpn.scpt"
osascript "$scriptlocation"
```

**#2.** create an applescript with name "vpn.scpt", place it under the path mentioned in the bash-script and place the following code inside:

```
set wlanssid to do shell script "networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -c 24-"
connectVPN(wlanssid)

on connectVPN(SSID)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
            local VPNService
            if (SSID = "XYZXYZ") then --WLANNAME
                set VPNService to service "XYZXYZ-VPN" --VPNNAME
                set isConnected to connected of current configuration of VPNService
                if not isConnected then
                    connect VPNService
                end if
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end connectVPN
```

This script will be executed everytime your computer connects to a "Captive Network"
and if the SSID of the WLAN is called "XYZXYZ" it will start the VPN-Connection with name XYZXYZ-VPN

The script can be modified to support multiple captive networks.

Also its possible to add Growl-Notifications to the Script.
My complete Script looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Rtp9EqQR

Comment: This is potentially useful, but it isn't at all a question. Might you have a better place to host it?

Comment: I agree it should be somewhere else - but in the meantime, that's a life saver ;-)

Comment: related http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x

Comment: Why do you put the Applescript in that location? Generally you should avoid adding or editing things in /System/Library. I would recommend that you put the Applescript in /Library somewhere, why not /Library/Scripts? Otherwise a good and interesting post!

Comment: Self-answers are alright, but they *should* be in the form of question + answer nevertheless. (You can accept your own answer a few days after posting it.)

Comment: Agree w/ echristopherson, I would host the solution as a Github Gist or Github code repo. And just link to it from here. Or dual host the code here and there.